# linear models for ANOVA

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, anova

I'm a bit desperate, as my exam is tomorrow.
Say I have the data for an ANOVA with 2 independent factors. According to my teacher, I would write the linear model on RStudio as:

`lm(score ~ 1+ A + B + A:B, data=mydata1, contrasts=list(A=contr.sum, B=contr.sum))`

I've faced an exercise in which he says, essencially, would this model be correct for a 2 way ANOVA?

`lm(score ~ A + B + A:B, data=mydata1, contrasts=list(A=contr.sum, B=contr.sum))`

I'm not sure what difference the "+1" makes on the LM, I assumed it changed the y for x=0, but I'm really not sure. Would it be appropriate to use?

Could anyone help me? Sorry if terms are wrong, my first language isn't english.

Comment: By default, `lm()` assumes that you want the intercept (`1 +`), so there is no difference between the two lines. If you don't want the intercept, changed to `0 + `.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg